# Update subject of incoming mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying toremove the RES: and ENC: (response and forwarding in Portuguese) upon receiving a message (by rule already sent to the folder referenced in the code).

Although the code works, in msgbox the subject is displayed without the prefixes, it does not refresh the subject.

I guess it has something to do with the ByVal or ByRef; i've tried both, and it goes as I described with ByVal, while with the byRef doesn't even run.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inboxItems = 
    objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("TESTA").Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem     
    Dim assunto As String
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        assunto = Replace(Replace(Item.Subject, "RES: ", ""), "ENC: ", "")
        Item.Subject = assunto
        MsgBox (assunto)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't tweak event handler signatures. If the event is defined with a `ByRef` parameter, then the handler for it needs a `ByRef` parameter. Watch the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane: if you're in the handler and it says "(General)", then that's just dead code, not an event handler. A handler for `inboxItems` would say `inboxItems` in the top-left dropdown.

Comment: Make sure the handler signature matches the event definition, then place a breakpoint (F9) on the `assunto =` assignment; run the macro; when the breakpoint is hit, press F8 to step-through line by line, and hover variables to see their values, or use the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) or *locals* toolwindow to view them - could it be that the subject doesn't contain `"RES: "` but `"RES:"` (without the space)?

Comment: Doesn't refresh the subject where? In your inbox?  If that's what you're after, you probably just need to save the `MailItem`.  It's the same thing as manually editing the subject line on an inbox item.  If you try to close it, you get the "properties changed, do you want to save" dialog.  It doesn't do anything unless you actually save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just forget ByVal and ByRef.
Add this string after last MsgBox:

Item.Save